# How to Setup Github Pages for account?

Tags: github

I am trying to figure out how to setup github pages for **account** rather than for a `repository`.

E.g

I want the blog address to be like this:

`xxx.github.io` rather than `xxx.github.io/repo`. Therefore when i go to `xxx.github.io`the static markdown pages should appear rather than a 404 page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for Pages' [user / organization](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#user--organization-pages) sites. The official site has a good [getting started guide](https://pages.github.com/), but the first bit is the most important one:

> ### Create a repository
>
> Head over to [GitHub](https://github.com/) and [create a new repository](https://github.com/new) named *username*.github.io, where *username* is your username (or organization name) on GitHub.
>
> If the first part of the repository doesn’t exactly match your username, it won’t work, so make sure to get it right.

So, instead of creating a `gh-pages` *branch* as you would for a project site, you must create a *repository* that matches your user name.